# Primes in shifted geometric progressions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Are there integers $a,b,r\in\mathbb Z$ such that there are infinitely many primes of the form $ar^n+b$ with $n\in\mathbb N$?

(I added the [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag because I suspect that the answer to the above question is contained in the literature.)

Comment: I suspect the answer is unknown.

Comment: In fact, I would bet that there does not currently exist either a proof or a disproof. Do you have reason to expect otherwise?

Comment: @quasi - Thanks for your comments! The finiteness of Fermat or Mersenne primes being open, the answer to the question cannot be No. I have seen many particular cases of the question, but I have never seen it asked in this level of generality (which looks natural to me). Also I know next to nothing about number theory.

Comment: If there was a known example which provably had infinitely many primes, it would surely be as well known as the currently open status for the case of Fermat primes or Mersenne primes. Thus you should not expect a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, we don't know.

In some sense, we are very very far from knowing this. Many of our results of the shape "There are infinitely many primes in the sequence..." are based ultimately on sieving. To use these sieves, we care very much about how sparse/dense the sequence is.

For results like Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, the sequences are of the form $an + b$, for fixed $a$ and $b$, as $n$ varies. These sequences have positive density in the integers.

That's about the limit of what we can prove. We don't know of a any polynomial $f(n) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree larger than $1$ such that $f(n)$ takes prime values infinitely many times. These sequences are sparse among the integers. There are several conjectures in this area, none of them proven (Schinzel's Hypothesis H, Bateman-Horn, and others).

What you're asking about is an exponential function $f(n)$, which is even more sparse in comparison to polynomials. We should expect this to be much harder than polynomial results.

I will note that if you remove the requirement that everything be an integer, you can specially construct exponentially distributed functions that *almost* take infinitely many primes. See for example [Mill's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant), which is the smallest number $A$ such that
$$ \lfloor A^{3^{n}} \rfloor $$
is always prime for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (This number does in fact exist). But this is more a statement about how exponential functions grow really rapidly and primes are much more dense than exponentially distributed points, so with lots of fiddling (and relying on the floor function to allow wiggle-room, some sort of locally constant behavior) you can engineer this constant.